Why torch.autograd.Function backward pass a grad_output?
my goal is to understand torch.autograd.Function. The problem is I don't understand why backward need grad_output.
What I've tried:

Read Learning PyTorch with Examples
The Learning PyTorch with Examples teach how to define autograd functions. I understand for LegendrePolynomial3, the forward should be ½ * (5x³ - 3x). However, I don't understand why the backward need grad_output.
class LegendrePolynomial3(torch.autograd.Function):
  """
  We can implement our own custom autograd Functions by subclassing
  torch.autograd.Function and implementing the forward and backward passes
  which operate on Tensors.
  """

  @staticmethod
  def forward(ctx, input):
    """
    In the forward pass we receive a Tensor containing the input and return
    a Tensor containing the output. ctx is a context object that can be used
    to stash information for backward computation. You can cache arbitrary
    objects for use in the backward pass using the ctx.save_for_backward method.
    """
    ctx.save_for_backward(input)
    # ½ * (5x³ - 3x)
    return 0.5 * (5 * input ** 3 - 3 * input)

  @staticmethod
  def backward(ctx, grad_output):
    """
    In the backward pass we receive a Tensor containing the gradient of the loss
    with respect to the output, and we need to compute the gradient of the loss
    with respect to the input.
    """
    input, = ctx.saved_tensors
    # d/dx ½ * (5x³ - 3x)
    # d/dx (½ * 5x³) - (½ * 3x)
    #      (3 * ½ * 5x²) - (1 * ½ * 3)
    #      1.5 * (5x² - 1)
    return grad_output * 1.5 * (5 * input ** 2 - 1)




The grad_output means the gradient of the output of that layer. Let x be the input of the function f and output y (y = f(x)). The grad_output should equal dL/dy. Using this will help you to calculate dL/dx using chain rule.

I don't get it. Can you help me understand? In the backward pass we receive a Tensor containing the gradient of the loss with respect to the output, and we need to compute the gradient of the loss with respect to the input.. Let say we have cubic polynomial, y = a + bx + cx**2 + dx**3, since it's respect to output, I am assuming this as output from forward. Will the backward be called 3 times? Let say we use Least Squares as the loss function and Gradient Descent as the optimizer grad_y_pred = 2 * (y_pred - y) -> grad_y_pred * x, then grad_y_pred * x ** 2, grad_y_pred * x ** 3?

Naively, if you do not define the above function, then to calculate the gradient of the loss wrt to the input (x), then you have to call backward 5 times (3 for the multiply with coefficients and 2 for the power). But by defining the above equation, you only have to backward just once.

Let b * x = t_1, c * x ** 2 = t_2, d * x ** 3 = t_3, we will just talk about t_2 case: dL/dx = dL/dy * dy/dt_2 * dt_2/dx = grad_y_pred * 1 * c * 2 * x
